# List removal error in Pygame 1.9.2a0 after collision detection

Tags: python, list, vector, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to make a breakout clone in Python 3.2.5 using Pygame 1.9.2a0.
The code is way more complex than what is really needed, but this was my first program in python/pygame and I am used to having stuff split up in their own classes/objects.

Anyways - the problem at hand is when my ball is colliding with the bricks, it detects to collision, but it doesn't remove them from the drawing - and if it isn't removed from the drawing it essentially isn't removed from the list.

```
        for brick in bricks_.bricks:
        if brick.collidepoint((ball_.pos.x+ball_.rad), (ball_.pos.y+ball_.rad)) or (brick.collidepoint((ball_.pos.x-ball_.rad),(ball_.pos.y-ball_.rad))):
            ball_.speed.y = -ball_.speed.y
            to_remove = [brick]
            for brick in to_remove:
                bricks_.bricks.remove(brick)
```

I tried implementing a technique which was found on stackoverflow from an earlier question, but it still doesn't work.

When I put the code inside the drawing function it removed the block before drawing it again. The thing is that I am only running my create bricks function once, so I don't understand why it is drawing the bricks which was removed from the list.

This is the create and draw function:

```
def create(self):
    y_margin = 40
    self.bricks = []
    for i in range(2):  
        """ Calculates x margin by subtracting by the number of pixels the blocks will take,
        divides this on 2 so you get the "spacing" on both sides of the blocks. 
        Subtracts half a block width from this number and then it's aligned perfectly.
        I do not know why I need to subtract half a block. 
        """
        x_margin = ((screen[0]-8*BRICK_W)/2)-(BRICK_W/2)
        for j in range(8):
            self.pos = (Vector2D((x_margin), (y_margin)))
            self.bricks.append(pygame.Rect(self.pos.x, self.pos.y, BRICK_W, BRICK_H))
            x_margin += BRICK_W+5
        y_margin += BRICK_H+5

def draw(self):
    for brick in self.bricks:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen_, WHITE, brick)
```

Since I decided to for the easy road with collisiondetection I get another error, which I think will disappear if the blocks did. Here is a picture of the game in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0thU6.gif.

The whole code for people who wants to take a look:
*(The state system is not beautiful, but atleast it works for this low-level code.)*

```
 # Standard libraries
    import sys, math, random

# Importing third party libraries
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Global constants
screen = (600, 600)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0 ,0)
PLATFORM_W = 100
PLATFORM_H = 20
ball_dia = 20
BRICK_W = 30
BRICK_H = 15


# Set screen
screen_ = pygame.display.set_mode(screen, 0 , 32)

# Platform Y coordinate
platform_Y = screen[1] - PLATFORM_H - 10 #This can be modified to fit aesthetics 

# Restrictions 
platform_MAX_X = screen[0] - PLATFORM_W
BALL_MAX_X = screen[0] - ball_dia+PLATFORM_H
BALL_MAX_Y = screen[1] - ball_dia


## ======================================*Vector2D*============================================== ##

class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(Self):
        return 'Vector(X: {x}, Y: {y})'.format(x = self.x, y = self.y)

    def __add__(self, b):
        return Vector2D(self.x + b.x, self.y +b.y)

    def __sub__(self, b):
        return Vector2D(self.x - b.x, self.y - b.y)

    def __mul__(self, b):

        try:
            b = float(b)
            return Vector2D(self.x * b, self.y * b)
        except ValueError:
            print("Ooops! Right value must be a float")
            raise

    def magnitue(self):
        try:
            m = self.magnitude()
            return Vector2D(self.x / m, self.y / m)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("Ooops, cannot normalize a zero vector")
            raise

    def copy(self):
        return Vector2D(self.x, self.y)



    """
    Get distance is basically getting the distance from a to b, 
    in this case vector a and vector b
    """
def get_distance(a, b):
        """ Using the distance formula which is derived from the Pythagorean theorem,
        http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php """

        a = Vector2D(a.x, a.y)
        b = Vector2D(b.x, b.y)

        return (((((a.x-b.x)**2)+((a.y-b.y)**2)))**.5)

## =========================================*Platform*=========================================== ##


class Platform:
    """ This is the platform that the player can control in x direction with arrow keys """
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = screen[0]/2 - PLATFORM_W/2
        self.y = platform_Y
        self.width = PLATFORM_W
        self.height = PLATFORM_H
        self.pos = Vector2D(self.x, self.y)
        self.tileRect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def clique(self):
        """ This is the one doing the magic to the Platform by getting the new x coordinates from
        the input function. It then updates it's position data accordingly and draws the Platform
        on the new information. """
        self.x = Input().x
        self.pos = Vector2D(self.x, self.y)

        # Making a variable that is equal to the rectangle platform
        # This will be used for collision detection.
        self.tileRect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen_, BLUE, (self.pos.x, self.pos.y, self.width, self.height))



platform_ = Platform()

## ===========================================*Bricks*========================================= ##


class Bricks:
    """ Bricks that will be removed after hit by the ball.
    They are created using for loops. Change the ranges on the for loops to change
    amounts of bricks """
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def create(self):
        y_margin = 40
        self.bricks = []
        for i in range(2):  
            """ Calculates x margin by subtracting by the number of pixels the blocks will take,
            divides this on 2 so you get the "spacing" on both sides of the blocks. 
            Subtracts half a block width from this number and then it's aligned perfectly.
            I do not know why I need to subtract half a block. 
            """
            x_margin = ((screen[0]-8*BRICK_W)/2)-(BRICK_W/2)
            for j in range(8):
                self.pos = (Vector2D((x_margin), (y_margin)))
                self.bricks.append(pygame.Rect(self.pos.x, self.pos.y, BRICK_W, BRICK_H))
                x_margin += BRICK_W+5
            y_margin += BRICK_H+5

    def draw(self):
        for brick in self.bricks:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen_, WHITE, brick)


bricks_ = Bricks()

## ========================================*Ball*============================================ ##


class Ball:
    """ A ball that will move, change direction if it hits platform, walls or bricks.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.rad = ball_dia/2
        self.speed = Vector2D(0, 0)
        self.pos = Vector2D(platform_.x+(PLATFORM_W/2), platform_.y-self.rad)
        self.status = 0
        self.gameover = False

    def move(self):
        ball_.speed = input_.speed
        ball_.pos += ball_.speed

        """ 
        Basic wall detection. Check all walls, subtracts the radius of the ball.
        """
        if self.pos.x > BALL_MAX_X - self.rad:
            self.pos.x = BALL_MAX_X - self.rad
            self.speed.x *= -1
        if self.pos.x < 0 + self.rad:
            self.pos.x = 0 + self.rad
            self.speed.x *= -1
        if self.pos.y > BALL_MAX_Y - self.rad:
            self.gameover = True
        if self.pos.y < 0 + self.rad:
            self.pos.y = 0 + self.rad
            self.speed.y *= -1


        """
        Inter is the centre position of the rectangle platform. This can be used
        for collision detection. """
        inter = Vector2D(platform_.pos.x+PLATFORM_W/2, platform_.pos.y-PLATFORM_H/2)
        d = get_distance(inter, self.pos)

        """ Here we are checking if the rectangle platform are colliding with the point 
        ball's coordinates + its radius. If that is the case we are also checking which
        side of the platform the ball is colliding on and having two different multipliers
        giving it a feel of randomness and having a bounce to the other direction,
        this we get by multiplying it by -1 (i.e)"""
        if platform_.tileRect.collidepoint((self.pos.x+self.rad), (self.pos.y+self.rad)) or (platform_.tileRect.collidepoint((self.pos.x-self.rad),(self.pos.y-self.rad))):
            if self.pos.x > inter.x:
                self.speed.x *= -random.randrange(1,4)
                self.speed.y *= -random.randrange(1,4)
            if self.pos.x < inter.x:
                self.speed.x *= -random.randrange(2, 4)
                self.speed.y *= -random.randrange(2, 4)

        for brick in bricks_.bricks:
            if brick.collidepoint((ball_.pos.x+ball_.rad), (ball_.pos.y+ball_.rad)) or (brick.collidepoint((ball_.pos.x-ball_.rad),(ball_.pos.y-ball_.rad))):
                ball_.speed.y = -ball_.speed.y
                to_remove = [brick]
                for brick in to_remove:
                    bricks_.bricks.remove(brick)

        if self.speed.x > 10:
            self.speed.x *= 0.5
        if self.speed.x < -10:
            self.speed.x *= 0.5
        if self.speed.y > 10:
            self.speed.y *= 0.5
        if self.speed.y < -10:
            self.speed.y *= 0.5

        ball_.draw()

    def collisions(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        if self.gameover == False:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen_, WHITE, (int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)), int(self.rad))


ball_ = Ball()



## ======================================*Engine*============================================== ##

class Engine:
    """ The engine initiates the game, takes care of events,
    show stats and messages and basically run all the other parts
    of the program """
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True
        self.retarded = False
        pygame.display.set_caption("Rektball by #TeamRekt")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        if pygame.font:
            self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        else:
            self.font = None


    """ 
    The eventhandler is a function that will check pygame.events,
    for either pygame.QUIT or the ESC button. If either is executed it will set the boolean
    to false and it will quit pygame using the built in pygame.quit() function.
    """
    def event_handler(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.alive = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.alive = False
                    pygame.quit()

    """ 
    Show message will basically show a message in the middle of the screen.
    It will use blit to create/render/draw/show the text.
    """
    def show_message(self, message):
        if self.font:
            size = self.font.size(message)
            font_surface = self.font.render(message, False, WHITE)
            x = (screen[0] - size[0]) / 2
            y = (screen[1] - size[1]) /2
            screen_.blit(font_surface, (x,y))


    """ 
    The run-loop which runs this whole game. Everything is handled in this loop.
    """
    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.event_handler()
            screen_.fill(BLACK)
            self.time_passed = self.clock.tick(30)
            statrun.Starts()

            if statrun.start == False:
                statrun.Starts()

            statrun.Runs()

            if ball_.gameover == True:
                statrun.Gameovers()

            pygame.display.update()

## =======================================*Input*============================================= ##


class Input:
    """ This will take care of inputs,
    i.e. keys being pressed down and use it to change
    parts of the code to move the ball, the platform etc. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = platform_.pos.x
        self.speed = Vector2D(0,0)
        self.status = False
        self.check_input()

    def check_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 10
            if self.x < 0:
                self.x = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 10
            if self.x > platform_MAX_X:
                self.x = platform_MAX_X
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and (self.status == False):
            self.status = True
            self.speed = Vector2D((-random.randrange(4, 10)),(-random.randrange(4,10)))


input_ = Input()    

## ==================================================================================== ##

class State_run:
    """
    This was supposed to be part of a bigger state-machine code,
    but after hitting the wall for too many hours I decided to abandon
    the project, but keeping a little bit of the structure.
    It is being called by boolean in the run function inside the engine object/class.
    This is not a very good solution, but as I said, I have spent a few hours (days...), 
    and I just had to wrap this up. 
    """


    """ The init function will start the boolean circus, 
    although the boolean will not be used if it works as planned,
    it's a fallback boolean. """
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = False

    def Starts(self):
        platform_.draw()
        ball_.draw()
        bricks_.create()
        bricks_.draw()
        self.start = True

    def Runs(self):
        input_.check_input()
        if input_.status != True:
            Engine().show_message("Press space to start game")
        if input_.status == True:
            ball_.move()
            platform_.clique()
            bricks_.draw()

    def Wins(self):
        Engine().show_message("You have won the game")

    def Gameovers(self):
        Engine().show_message("You have lost the game")
        ball_.speed = Vector2D(0,0)

statrun = State_run()

## ==================================================================================== ##



""" Runs the program by first initiating pygame using the builtin function, pygame.init(),
then it runs the Engine().run() function which is doing all the work. """
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()

    Engine().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for brick in to_remove:
    bricks_.bricks.remove(brick)
```

The 'brick' in the second loop shadows the previous 'brick' in the first loop. It has to be changed.

```
for i in to_remove:
    bricks_.bricks.remove(i)
```

or get the second `for` loop out of first loop. I think you are collecting objects to be removed based on some conditions. You have to deindent the second `for` loop, if so there's no need to change the loop variable name.

The 'to_remove' list has a single element. It seems it has to have multiple elements, initilize this to an empty list like `to_remove = []` out of the loop and append objets like `to_remove.append(brick)`.

It seems this function call can be changed. `brick.collidepoint((ball_.pos.x+ball_.rad), (ball_.pos.y+ball_.rad))` to `brick.collidepoint(ball_.pos.x + ball_.rad, ball_.pos.y + ball_.rad)`.

```
to_remove = []
cpoint1 = brick.collidepoint(ball_.pos.x + ball_.rad, ball_.pos.y + ball_.rad)
cpoint2 = brick.collidepoint(ball_.pos.x - ball_.rad, ball_.pos.y - ball_.rad)
for brick in bricks_.bricks:
    if  cpoint1 or cpoint2:
        ball_.speed.y = -ball_.speed.y
        to_remove.append(brick)

for brick in to_remove:
    bricks_.bricks.remove(brick)
```

Comment: Found my problem.

 It's in 'def Starts(self):
        platform_.draw()
        ball_.draw()
        bricks_.create()
        bricks_.draw()
        self.start = True'

Which was being run all the time, when I thought it wasn't...